# Given a list of words, I am to read them using scanf("%c", &c), create a string out of the letters and print the rest unchanged

Tags: c

For instance, in a sentence such as

Its a great day. Right?

I want to keep reading until I reach a non-letter character, call my helper function on each string created and print the rest unchanged.

This is what I have so far but it only prints the first letter numerous times

```
  void string_create(void) {
      char word[1000+1] = {0};
  int i = 0;
  int j=0;
  char c = 0;
  while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1) {
    if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {  
      word[i] = c;
      i++; 

    }

    else { 
      printf("%s", word);
      i=0;
      printf("%c", c);
  }

}
}
```

In the end for now, without going into details of the helper function, it should simply print the original sentence unchanged.

Current output:

```
Its ats great dayat.dayat Right?Right
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the code you show. Or use an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: I also recommend you learn about [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) and the other standard [character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: The change you made, did it solve your problem? Then please add a comment or possibly an answer about it. If it fixed your problem, then the edit made your question worthless since it no longer have any problem. Remember that this site isn't only to help you right here and now, but also to help future visitors with the same or a similar problem. If they see this question and it doesn't have the problem you ask about, they will become very confused.

Comment: And if the change you made caused a new problem, then leave it and post a *new* question. Otherwise the description won't make sense. I suggest you take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I dont think posting a new question will help, sorry but I changed the output like you said

Comment: I rolled back to the original question, which is [answered by Mohamed Ghieth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807731/440558). When you fix that you can post a new question with the new problem.

Comment: You have two ***different*** problems, you need to ask two different questions. Partly modifying this existing question makes it nonsensical.

Comment: @new_hello_world -- please don't edit your question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. There are two answers below that respond to the code you had posted; I have rolled back to the version with that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void string_create(void)
{
char word[1000+1] = {0};
int i = 0;
char c = 0;

scanf("%c",&c);
while ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
{
    word[i++]=c;
    while((c=getchar()!='\n')&&(c!=EOF));     //to remove white space
    scanf("%c",&c);
}

printf("%s",word);
}

int main()
{
    string_create();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
q
w
e
r
t
y
1
qwerty
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.205 s
Press any key to continue.
```

you can also give new line(enter) instead of 1

you can also use this

```
scanf("%1000[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]",word);
```

it only read letters

Comment: the format for reading has been pre-specified. it is the one in the title :(

Comment: Hello, I removed  this line: while((c=getchar()!='\n')&&(c!=EOF));  since scanf needs to be the only method of reading input. It now prints the first word "its", but stops after that

Comment: The scanf leaves '\n' in buffer the while((c=getchar()!='\n')&&(c!=EOF)) is to remove that or use this format in while loop scanf(" %c",&c); to remove.

Comment: Note that `s` is not part of the scanset directive. Also, you should always specify a max width with `%s` and `%[]` to avoid buffer overflow: `%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]s` --> `%1000[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here (infinite loop) :

```
while((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
```

Use **if** instead of **while**.

Comment: I added an if statement but it does not solve the problem (made changes to the output)